# Kubernetes- What's the best way to switch the context between multiple cluster's in CICD?

Tags: microservices

What's the best way to switch the context between multiple cluster's in CICD?

I am currently using `kubectl config use-context <CLUSTER_NAME>` . I heard there is a best way to switch the context using --context flag. I am not finding the exact command to use.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you mentioned, it's simply something like `kubectl get pods --context=<context-name>` for instance, for easier auto-completion you can use something like zsh or bash auto-completion: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/

Comment: My question was basically pointing to switching the context on CI machine. Trying to prevent using ```kubectl config use-context <CLUSTER_NAME>``` command.